# How can javascript distinguish one button of a form from another?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here the code of index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Band</td>
            <td>Indx</td>
            <td>Send</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Iron Maiden</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>
                <form action="" class="form" method="POST">
                    <input class="name" name="name" type="hidden" value="Bruce">
                    <input class="band" name="band" type="hidden" value="Iron Maiden">
                    <input class="indx" name="indx" type="hidden" value="95">
                    <button class ="send" type="submit">SEND<button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>James</td>
            <td>Metallica</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>
                <form action="" class="form" method="POST">
                    <input class="name" name="name" type="hidden" value="James">
                    <input class="band" name="band" type="hidden" value="Metallica">
                    <input class="indx" name="indx" type="hidden" value="90">
                    <button class ="send" type="submit">SEND<button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="result"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function(){
            $('.form').submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    data: $('.form').serialize(),
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'remote.php',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('.result').html(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the code of remote.php

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $band = $_POST['band'];
    $indx = $_POST['indx'];
    $up = $indx * 2;

    $output = '
        <div id="rock-modal" class="modal fade in" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                            <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
                            Rock Modal
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        The band '.$band.' has an up index of '.$up.'!!!
                    </div><!-- /modal-body -->
                </div><!-- /modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /modal-dialog modal-lg -->
        </div><!-- /modal fade in-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#rock-modal").modal("show");
        </script>';
    echo $output;
```

When I have only one row in the table (ex.: Iron Maiden) I receive the bootstrap modal with the correspondent info. When I have more than one row in the table (ex.: Iron Maiden and Metallica) I receive the results only from the last row (in this case Metallica) also when I click on the button of the first row. If I inserted another row and click on the first or on the second button I receive back the modal always with the info of the last row.

How can I say to the javascript which button I'm exactly clicking?

Comment: Make sure both buttons have a unique name or id...

Comment: use unique id for each button

Comment: You can assign class for each button,     $(".send1").click(function(){ // do button actions here });

Comment: Did any of you even spend 30 seconds trying to **understand** the problem before rambling on about buttons?

Comment: @N.B. good call! The problem if I have different classes or ids for each button I have to have lots of js functions. If I have a table with thousand rows I would need thousand js functions, one for each button.

Comment: You wouldn't. Check my answer to see why.

Comment: I couldn't expect a clearer explanation and such a perfect answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having comes from having multiple forms, and then ultimately serializing the wrong one.

You bound a submit event to anything containing `.form` thus being able to catch submit event of any form.
The line I'm referring to is this one:

```
$('.form').submit(function(){
```

However, the problem lies in what you actually sent via ajax, and the culprit is the following line:

```
data: $('.form').serialize(),
```

When you have one form, that line works fine. When you have more than one form, then how does jQuery know which form to serialize? <strike>It will, to my assumption, select the LAST form because the selector `$('.form');` will select all forms.</strike>
It will serialize ALL forms, but when values reach the PHP script - the ones propagated will be the values of **last** form due to field names being the same in all the forms.

So what you have to do is modify your function where you bind the submit event. You have to tell that function "please serialize the form that's actually submitted". You do it via:

```
$(function(){
        $('.form').submit(function(e){
            $.ajax({
                data: $(e.currentTarget).serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'remote.php',
                success: function(data){
                    $('.result').html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Notice the change in the callback function and `data` line. That means you do not have to tell javascript which button was pressed. What you have to do is serialize the submitted form.

Answer (score -1):

Use unique id for forms or buttons. then call them with:

```
$('#form-one button') // if you set ID to form
```

or

```
$('#my-button-id') // if you set id to button.
```

IDs must be unique to follow HTML rules and for jQuery to work

Answer (score -1):

Create unique class value for each button created so you can reference it in jquery.
On your example, both are defined with 'send'. You can add another class value inside class attibute for both buttons and set a unique value like:

```
<button class ="send button_1" type="submit">SEND<button>

<button class ="send button_2" type="submit">SEND<button>
```

Aditionally, you can use unique id to jquery take specific actions.